# Copy a file from source directory to target base directory and maintain source path

Tags: macos, find

Forgive me, I am probably not using the right terms to describe the problem and misunderstanding the most basic usage for a couple of common commands.

I have a simple find statement that is locating files that I want to copy.  I want to tack on the -exec cp {} and have cp copy the file from the source directory to a new base directory, but include the full path.  For example:

- `find . -name *.txt` locates `/user/username/projects/source.txt`
- `cp {} [now what?]` copies the file to `/user/newuser/projects/source.txt`

Answer (score 0):

```
rsync -rlpv --files-from=<(find ...) /user/username/projects /user/newuser
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can be sure that all of the subdirectories exist, then this is a fun option:

```
cd /user/username/
find . -name \*.gz | sed 's/\.\(.*\)/.\1 ..\/newuser\1/' | xargs -n2 cp
```